# Unable to understand when "i "value is constant and 2 dimension array works fine on getting the value from each row correctly

Tags: excel, selenium, loops, apache-poi, constants

Code :

```
public String[][] getExcelData(String excellocation, String sheetName) {
    try {
        String dataSets[][] = null;
        FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream(new File(excellocation));

        // Create Workbook instance holding reference to .xlsx file
        XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(file);
        // Get first/desired sheet from the workbook
        XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheet(sheetName);
        // count number of active rows
        int totalRow = sheet.getLastRowNum();
        // count number of active columns in row
        int totalColumn = sheet.getRow(0).getLastCellNum();
        // Create array of rows and column
        dataSets = new String[totalRow][totalColumn];
        // Iterate through each rows one by one
        Iterator<Row> rowIterator = sheet.iterator();
        DataFormatter formatter = new DataFormatter();
        int i = 0;
        while (rowIterator.hasNext()) {
            Row row = rowIterator.next();
            // For each row, iterate through all the columns
            Iterator<Cell> cellIterator = row.cellIterator();
            int j = 0;
            while (cellIterator.hasNext()) {

                Cell cell = cellIterator.next();
                if (cell.getStringCellValue().contains("TestCases")) {
                    break;
                }

                // Check the cell type and format accordingly
                switch (cell.getCellType()) {
                case Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC:
                    dataSets[i][j++] = cell.getStringCellValue();
                    System.out.println(cell.getStringCellValue());
                break;
                case Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING:
                    dataSets[i][j++] = cell.getStringCellValue();
                    System.out.println(cell.getStringCellValue());
                    break;
                }

            }

            System.out.println("");


        }
        file.close();
        return dataSets;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    String excellocation = "C:\\Users\\Sivaranjani Gopal\\Desktop\\siva.xlsx";
    String sheetName = "testdata";
    ExcelReaderpg excel = new ExcelReaderpg();
    Object[][] data = excel.getExcelData(excellocation, sheetName);
}
```

Note :

1.My Query is the value of i is always said to be 0. so dataset[0][1]  for 1st row

for second row it should be dataset [1][0] [1][1] and so on.

why does i value remain the same and i get the desired output.

Can some one explain the value of i and j implementation in the array

Comment: Where do you think you are changing the value of `i`?

Comment: @AxelRichter my question is exactly i value is not changing, but how could it read all the rows without i value being changed.   dataSets[0][1] is only first row first column so dataSets[1][1] should be second row first column, here dataSets[i][j+1] i value is to be changed from 0 to 1 right, else how it works?

Comment: Please try leaning the basics. The code you are showing changes the value of `j` using `j++` for each cell the `cellIterator` has. The value of `i` needs to be changed for each row the `rowIterator` has. Probably do using `i++` after `System.out.println("");` before getting next row of `rowIterator`.

Comment: @AxelRichter - the above code is working correctly and getting values from all the rows without i++ code in it. That is my question :(

Comment: The above code, as it is without `i++`, results in a `String[][] dataSets` where only `dataSets[0][n]` is filled with contents of the last row of the Excel as all rows are overwriting `dataSets[0]`. All other values in `String[][] dataSets` are `null`. For example `dataSets[1][0]` will be `null`, `dataSets[1][1]` will be null and so on.